# Email been marked as spam

Tags: email, spam

Friends, I tried a lot of changes, but no success to send the email correctly formated, I'm using the same domain to send mail and the email pass trough spf and authentication, but has been marked as spam for some accounts using gmail ou google app's.

The header's are:

```
    Delivered-To: destin@globo.com
Received: by 10.231.208.5 with SMTP id ga5cs194453ibb;
        Mon, 17 Jan 2011 11:08:33 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.142.213.18 with SMTP id l18mr4141524wfg.192.1295291312735;
        Mon, 17 Jan 2011 11:08:32 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <me@domain.com.br>
Received: from hm1315-29.locaweb.com.br (hm1315-29.locaweb.com.br [201.76.49.185])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id a70si8528144yhd.33.2011.01.17.11.08.32;
        Mon, 17 Jan 2011 11:08:32 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of me@domain.com.br designates 201.76.49.185 as permitted sender) client-ip=201.76.49.185;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of jaime@yachtbrasil.com.br designates 201.76.49.185 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=jaime@yachtbrasil.com.br
Received: from hm1974.locaweb.com.br (189.126.112.86) by hm1315-38.locaweb.com.br (PowerMTA(TM) v3.5r15) id h6i9r00nvfo8 for <destine@globo.com>; Mon, 17 Jan 2011 17:08:31 -0200 (envelope-from <me@domain.com.br>)
X-Spam-Status:  No
Received: from bart0020.locaweb.com.br (bart0020.email.locaweb.com.br [200.234.210.22])
    by hm1974.locaweb.com.br (Postfix) with ESMTP id 9C03511E00B5;
    Mon, 17 Jan 2011 17:08:31 -0200 (BRST)
X-LocaWeb-COR: locaweb_2009_x-mail
Received: from admin.domain.com.br (hm686.locaweb.com.br [200.234.200.116])
    (Authenticated sender: jaime@yachtbrasil.com.br)
    by bart0020.locaweb.com.br (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 4B2F08CAFD6B;
    Mon, 17 Jan 2011 17:08:31 -0200 (BRST)
Message-ID: <1295291311.4d3493af36027@admin.domain.com.br>
Date: Mon, 17 Jan 2011 17:08:31 -0200
Subject: Domain - Assunto
From: Sistema <me@domain.com.br>
Reply-To: rodrigo <rodrigo@ymail.com>
To: balucia <destine@globo.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-Virus-Scanned: clamav-milter 0.96.5 at hm1974
X-Virus-Status: Clean
```

This header has been marked as spam, I had no more ideas how to fix it and there are people borrowing me about this.

Thanks and best regard's.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using your own mail server? You may want to check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys

This is an anti-spam feature used by many email providers, which requires you to register your domain so apps like gmail, etc. know it is not spam.

Comment: I paied for a web server by this smtp, but it appears that they don´t have domain keys instaled, can I do it for my self?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a content issue. You can use litmusapp to test it or any email provider solution will detect it and offer solutions. The one I founded Critsend.com offers this for example.

Comment: Great tip, I will try it, but I have done a few tests and I found that the content inside the email, like images and html where doing it!Thanks.